# How do insert an inner document in an existing document in mongodb in java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a document in collection names `user` which is as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "Password" : "xyz",
    "first_name" : "ABC",
    "last_name" : "PQR",
}
```

I want to insert an inner document `job_desc` having some entries like `job`, `place`, `salary` 
after modifying the `user` document becomes like this

```
{
    "_id" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "Password" : "xyz",
    "first_name" : "ABC",
    "last_name" : "PQR",
    "doc" : { "job_desc" : "Design Engineer", "place" : "Bengaluru", "salary" : 40K USD }
}
```

I tried using `append` but it is for new document entry and then using `$set` but it is used for replacing the specified value. How do I meet my requirement?

Comment: I dont care about reputation, but you dint request for java code in your question, you just mentioned $set operator and given the sample document,next time be more specific about what exactly you want

Comment: @Disposer sir please see the question. It was originally asked in java. I thought everyone is trying in java only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a new nested object using Java

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("doc",new BasicDBObject("job","Design Engineer").append("place","Bengaluru").append("salary", "40K USD"));
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("_id","abc@gmail.com");
    BasicDBObject set = new BasicDBObject("$set", doc);
    collection.update(query, set);

// result doc
{
    "_id" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "Password" : "xyz",
    "first_name" : "ABC",
    "last_name" : "PQR",
    "doc" : {
        "job" : "Design Engineer",
        "place" : "Bengaluru",
        "salary" : "40K USD",
    }
}
```

In mongo console use this code for adding just one value to your existing nested doc(or event non existing):

```
db.collection.update({"_id":"abc@gmail.com"}, {$set : {'doc.newField' : 'newValue'}})
```

the result would be:

```
// modified doc
{
    "_id" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "Password" : "xyz",
    "first_name" : "ABC",
    "last_name" : "PQR",
    "doc" : {
        "job" : "Design Engineer",
        "place" : "Bengaluru",
        "salary" : 500,
        "newField" : "newValue"
    }
}
```

Comment: where to specify the existing document in the code given?

Comment: What is this my friend. BTW it is in rupees and please solve the problem. Thanks for the comment. It was funny :)

Comment: @SatishPatel No offence but I don't get out of bed for 500K rupees, unless I am travelling. I think the author here was on the right track, but as I said, you probably want to `$set` all of the nested values in the object rather than just one property. Therefore I was giving @Disposer a chance to alter that because I know they basically understand that principle. Nonetheless the required code is in my comment. But if your boss needs more knowledge on board, then yes 600K USD per annum would be an acceptable offer.

Comment: @Neil-Lunn, you can edit entire of answers if you want. Something that I love about your answers is the details of them, you nicely describe the operators and everything, I believe I cant never explain like you ;).

Comment: Don't sell yourself short. If there is one thing I certainly notice is peoples continued attempts to help others and the quality of those attempt getting better. Your responses are increasingly getting more informative. So I beg to differ. You are going to be able to explain better than me. If you think you cannot now, then you will some day. I think you're doing just fine right now.

Comment: thanks @Neil-Lunn, as you know, you are my mongo guru ;)

Comment: @NeilLunn Sir, I am a student and I am doing my personal project and I got stuck with it. And I deeply appreciate the effort. :) :)

Comment: @Disposer The answer given works well in mongodb console but  did not work with java.